# How to plot list if values with respect to its key of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, visualization

I have a dictionary with list of values

```
df_param = {};
for i in range(0,1000):
  df_param[i]=[[0]]
print(df_param)
```

```
df_param={0: [[0], [20], [20], [20], [5], [1], [5]], 1: [[0], [20], [20], [5], [1], [5]], 2: [[0], [20], [20], [5], [5]], 3: [[0], [20], [5], [5]], 4: [[0], [5], [5]], 5: [[0], [5]], 6: [[0]], 7: [[0]], 8: [[0], [20]], 9: [[0]], 10: [[0]]}
```

I need to plot each key in x-axis and the list of values in y-axis.

[image]

this is my code:

```
for i in range(0,1000):
  for j in range(0,10):
    curr = df1[j][i]['Classifier'][0]
    if(curr=='KNNClassifier'):
      df_param[i].append([df1[j][i]['Classifier'][1]['n_neighbors']])
print(df_param)
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for key, values in df_param.items():
    plt.plot(key, values)
plt.show()
```

I get the below error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-176b8a768873> in <module>
      1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      2 for key, values in df_param.items():
----> 3     plt.plot(key, values)
      4 plt.show()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    340 
    341         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
--> 342             raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
    343                              f"have shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")
    344         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (7, 1)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by plotting a list of values in the y axis. How would you draw a plot of `[5, [20], [20], [20], [5], [1], [5]]`? What kind of plot are you imagining?

Comment: A scatter plot probably

Comment: Is there a reason your list contains lists of single numbers, instead of it being a list of just numbers, like `[20, 20, 20, 5, 1, 5]`?

Comment: Even I wanted to make it a list like [20,20,20,5,1,5] but it is difficult for me to append values in that format. so I used list of arrays for each value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `df_param` is a `dict` of form:

`{x0: [[y0_a], [y0_b], ...], x1: [[y1_a], [y1_b], ...], ...}` and you wish to make a scatter plot of all the `(xk, yk_i)`, then you can first make a proper `xy` array with two columns `x` and `y`:

```py
import numpy as np

xy = np.array([
    (x, y) for x, lst in df_param.items()
    for sublst in lst for y in sublst
])
plt.plot(*xy.T, 'o')
```

[image]